# Netlify or Vercel build error on react18 + vite (v4) + Typescript with react-router-6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, vite, netlify

While added react-router in `./src/App.tsx` there was no problem on netlify or vercel build-time. But, error occurs when I imported them from a custom folder like...

[netlify-build-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ID5.png)

But in a local machine, it is ok while run: `yarn build`

[local-ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJS3i.png)

```
src
│___App.tsx
|___Router.tsx
│
└───pages
│   |___HomePage.tsx
|   |___Notfound.tsx
|   |___index.ts
```

I'm exporting all page components from `./src/pages/index.ts`.

> Node Version: 18.x

> Vite: 4.x

> Plugin: @vitejs/plugin-react

> Typescript: 4.9.x

repository: (PR) https://github.com/0xMahabub/react-vite-ts-swc-zustand/pull/2

**I have tried to figure this out but couldn't get it myself**
I wish to find the actual problem and its solution and get rid of this issue.
Then I can go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, you forgot to add files in `pages` directory to `staged` files when you were commiting them... because they are not in you repo
just write `git add .` (if you have .gitignore file!) in you root folder and then commit>push